# Replacing the first element of each group by its aggregation function

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
     'Y': [2, 4, 8, 10, 5]})
```

which looks as:

```
    X   Y
0   a   2
1   a   4
2   b   8
3   a   10
4   b   5
```

How to replace the first element of each group by `X` with the respective mean?

The expected output:

```
    X   Y
0   a   5.33
1   a   4.00
2   b   6.50
3   a   10.00
4   b   5.00
```

Sorry if this is a too basic question, but I am a newbie to Python (beginning its learning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for averages and set only first value per group in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['Y'] = np.where(df.X.duplicated(),df.Y,df.groupby("X")['Y'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
   X          Y
0  a   5.333333
1  a   4.000000
2  b   6.500000
3  a  10.000000
4  b   5.000000
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df.X.duplicated(), 'Y'] = df.groupby("X")['Y'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, quick question: is using duplicated() to get first row of group more efficient or is it more pandaic way? - only for my learning.

Comment: @SomeDude I think more efficient, groupby is obviously slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
g = df.groupby('X', as_index=False)
df.iloc[g.head(1).index] = g.mean()
```

Basically get the indexes of first rows of each group and replace them with mean values.

print(df):

```
   X          Y
0  a   5.333333
1  a   4.000000
2  b   6.500000
3  a  10.000000
4  b   5.000000
```